# How to query if the parameter is an array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this given array of ids assigned to a certain variable,

```
$post_id = array('756','754','752','750');
```

and then what I want is to get all posts, with ID which is inside the array. Is it possible to get all posts, preferably inside an array, which have IDs that correspond to the given array of IDs? This is for my Wordpress project and since I'm a newbie with this thing, I am a bit lost right now. Please guide me.:(

Thanks.

Comment: You have set your array, but where is your code for you trying to manipulate it? What is your specific problem? Stack Overflow isn't for writing your code for you. You need a guide and this isn't really a question. Start with php `foreach()` and a basic mysql tutorial.

Comment: yeah i wanted to get it using foreach(), i did not ask for lines of codes here @Blake, i just wanted to know how to do it. Thanks for your lovely comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) arrays.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE posts IN ('" . implode("','", $post_id) . "')";
```

I think you were looking for [MySQL's IN() clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
$post_id = array('756','754','752','750');

$postId = "'" . implode("','", $post_id) . "'";

$query = "SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE postId IN (".$postId.") ";
```